# To read obj file i use jpct but i can't find how to zoom on it

Tags: android, zooming, scale, jpct

I can load .obj with jpct library for that i use something like that:

```
                InputStream isObj = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Vanne.obj");
                InputStream isMtl = new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/Download/Vanne.mtl");
                Object3D[] object = Loader.loadOBJ(isObj, isMtl, 1.47f);
                mObject = object[0];
```

What i want to do now is changing zoom for the object 3D i try setting scale with: mObject.setScale(1.1f);  but i can't change it, anyone know how do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course change the scale factor, but that's not the same thing as a zoom. For proper zooming, modify the camera's fov (field of view): [Camera.setFOV()](http://www.jpct.net/doc/com/threed/jpct/Camera.html#setFOV(float))